# getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated

Tags: android, flutter

I am unable to fix this error on my flutter app.

```
    > Task :permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/sumeetpujari/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-6.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/ServiceManager.java:154: warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                                                                  ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning
warnings found and -Werror specified
```

The code :

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private boolean isBluetoothServiceEnabled() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround you need to check the SDK version and based on it make changes in the app.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
 bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getAdapter();
}else{
  bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager.getDefaultAdapter();
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()

Comment: there is no `BluetoothAdapter.getAdapter()` method available on any Android version, you probably meant to use `BluetoothManager.getAdapter()`

Comment: how can I solve this problem? I can't find any solution for this deprecated case

Answer (score 1):

To get the default `BluetoothAdapter` you have to get it from the `BluetoothManager` system service. The sample below is from `SomeActivity`. In this case *this* refers to an instance of an activity.

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
if (bluetoothManager == null) {
  /* Error handling */
}

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
  /* Error handling */
}
```

I have tested it with Android API 26 to API31.