# Flutter compileSdkVersion 31 cause "BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated"

Tags: flutter

I changed `SDK Version to 31` and cause the following error. I tried to update the `ServiceManager.java` according to this link [BluetoothAdapter deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894223/getdefaultadapter-in-bluetoothadapter-has-been-deprecated) but it does not work.

How can I solve this error? Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps solve the problem

1. Delete pubspec.lock
2. Run flutter pub cache repair
3. Run flutter pub get